# Find a special tag, replace it in source text its value

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a sample text with special tags.

```
Дата договора {Дата договора}
Номер договора {Номер договора} 
Место заключения договора {Место заключения договора} 
ФИО сотрудника {ФИО работника} 
ИИН сотрудника {ИИН работника} 
Документы сотрудника {Документ работника} 
Телефон сотрудника {Телефон работника} 
Место жительства сотрудника {Адрес проживания работника} 
Должность сотрудника {Должность} 
Дата выхода на работу {Дата выхода на работу} 
Срок действия договора до {Срок действия довогора до} 
Условия труда {Условия труда} 
Должностной оклад {Должностной оклад}
Место работы {Место работы} 
Режим работы {Режим работы}
```

The text between curly braces ({, }) is a special tag. The tag is a Django model:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The attribute `name` of Tag is a text between curly braces.

What I want is:

1. Find all spectags in sample text
2. Get their value
3. Replace those tags with their value in text

How to achieve this? I'd like to use regex but it might be slow, because those spectags are for documents that could be more than 100 page-long. Is there any 'textual algorithm' for this?

Comment: if you mentioned Django model, how do you expect it to be involved here?

Answer (score 1):

Try with, is uggly but functional

```
value = your_line.split("{")[-1].split("}")[0]
```